# Random sized array and exactly three ones in it

Tags: netlogo

Good morning,

I need to create a list of `[0,1]`, which length is defined by the user (global variable). There is an easy solution for this:

```
set listInd (list n-values numOfInd [random 2])
```

But I need to make sure, that the list has exactly three ones in it and they are placed on random positions. Is there a way to do this?

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create 3 random numbers (indices) and then create a list with `1` on the positions defined by this index list:

```
to-report rand-list[n k]
  let ind-list n-of k n-values n [?]
  report n-values n [ifelse-value (member? ? ind-list) [1][0]]
end
```

Usage:

```
show rand-list 10 3

; result:
; [0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to bergant's solution would be to gather the desired amount of ones and zeros, then mix them together randomly:

```
to-report rand-list [n k]
  let zeros n-values (n - k) [0]
  let ones n-values k [1]
  report shuffle sentence zeros ones
end
```